# How to keep add_header_above (in kableExtra) fixed when scrolling

Tags: r, kable, kableextra

I'm creating a table using kableExtra (HTML), and I've grouped columns using `add_header_above()`. I want the header row to stay fixed and visible when scrolling through a long table, so I've used `kable_styling(fixed_thead = TRUE)`. So far, so good.

When I scroll, the actual header row stays visible like it's supposed to, but the header-above row goes off the screen and is no longer visible. How can I make the header-above row stay visible on the screen, too?

Here's a reprex:

```
library(dplyr)
library(kableExtra)

starwars[1:11] %>% 
  kable(format="html") %>% 
  kable_styling(full_width = F,
                fixed_thead = T) %>% 
  add_header_above(c(" " =1,
                     "Looks" = 5,
                     "Stats" = 5))
```

This problem happens not only in the RStudio preview, but when opening up the knitted HTML file in (we've tried multiple browsers on multiple computers). It also happens if I instead put the kable in a fixed-height scroll box (which automatically keeps the header row fixed).